# Google Sheets Query > Filter rows based on text in a string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a recipe database on Sheet1. Each row is a recipe and each recipe has all of the ingredients listed in a single cell using JOIN in column B e.g. "Bread, Butter, Beans, Cheese".

On Sheet2, I have a client database. Each client has a list of dislikes, all of which are listed in a single cell, using JOIN e.g. "Sprouts, Celery, Fish".

On Sheet3, I would like to have a filtered list of all the recipes that do not contain ingredients that the client dislikes. Using a dropdown, I would like to choose the client and then see what recipes they would like.

After hours of back and forth with Sheets, I've conceded this is way above my pay grade.

Could anyone put an end to this mystery for me?

Here's a link to a demo sheet > [Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wn52w7uK-nY1n3LhrHZRD6nqQ7Ty0diQuXF-bpUtTA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please supply a sample of an expected outcome in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:B, NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B2:B, 
 SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(B1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0), ", ", "|"))))
```

[image: 0]